# How to retrieve XML formdata of a Document using Docusign RestAPI

Tags: docusignapi

> Hi,
>   How to retrieve XML formdata of a Document using Docusign RestAPI.

Comment: Please read the FAQ how to ask good questions. BTW reading the (http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation)[Doc] may help.

Comment: HI,
I have used Get Document from Envelope  RESTAPI,to download documents.In the rest API docs,it clearly says ,the documents will be downloaded in PDF byte stream only.
How can I retrieve XML formdata of the document.
IF there is any other API to retrieve xML FormData.Please suggest
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've provided the solution, if it works for you please accept as answer...

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to get the values of document form fields, this is documented in the [REST API Guide (v2)](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation) and there is also a [DocuSign API Walkthrough](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeRecipientStatus) that already demonstrates how to make the call, although it does not include the optional query parameter of "include_tabs" that you will have to add.  The call you want is-

**Get Envelope Recipient Status**

```
This returns the status for all recipients of a single envelope and identifies the current routing order. The current routing order is a number that matches up to the routingOrder for envelope recipients, which shows that the envelope has been sent to a recipient, but the recipient has not completed their actions.
```

**URL**:

```
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients
```

Optional query items: include_tabs={true or false}, include_extended={true or false}

**Formats**:

```
XML, JSON
```

**HTTP Method**:

```
GET
```

**Parameters**:

The only required parameter is the envelope ID. If the optional query include_tabs is set to true, the 
tabs associated with the recipient are returned. If the optional query include_extended is set to true, 
the extended properties are returned.

---

For instance, if you had a completed envelope with a textTab (Data Field) form field on the envelope called `DataField1` you make the above call with the optional URL parameter `?include_tabs=true` appended to the URL, among the other data that is returned you'd have something similar to this for the textTab and it's value:

```
"textTabs": [
      {
        "height": 11,
        "validationPattern": "",
        "validationMessage": "",
        "shared": "false",
        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
        "name": "Text",
        "value": "data goes here",
        "width": 108,
        "required": "true",
        "locked": "false",
        "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
        "disableAutoSize": "false",
        "tabLabel": "DataField1",
        "bold": "false",
        "italic": "false",
        "underline": "false",
        "documentId": "1",
        "recipientId": "6c8377fc-ff4e-45ba-b7f7-c7b9b168471c",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "202",
        "yPosition": "71",
        "tabId": "936c9ab6-f8b3-42e0-8870-52a024788319"
      }
```

You can then parse whatever information about the tabs you need, such as value, name, etc.